# Facebook not using my Open Graph meta data

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have added a Facebook share button to a web page, which works fine, but it does not use the correct data to share (mainly the image, picking a much to small one).

I have added the following to the pages HEAD section:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MyPageName">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/ShareImage.jpg">
```

But still the Facebook share button does not use this data.

I have used the Facebook debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) but still with no luck, it just shows the data that it is pulling from the page its self, not the data in the meta tags and states:

> **Inferred Property** The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> **Inferred Property** The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> **Tiny og:image** All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions, and preferably 1500x1500px. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: It's almost certainly that you're not actually serving those meta tags to facebook or are redirecting facebook to another URL via a HTTP redirect, a canonical meta tag, or an og:url tag pointing to a different URL